# OSM XML to GEOJSON in Python

Tags: python-3.x, openstreetmap

I am trying to learn Python and Open Street Map API. I want to download with python a small region and then convert it into Geojson. I tried with two python libraries(osm2geojson and osmtogeojson) to convert OSM xml to Geojson so far but I am getting errors in both of them. My code is the following using osm2geojson:

```
from OSMPythonTools.api import Api
api = Api()
bbox = api.query('map?bbox=-0.08918,51.47980,-0.08496,51.48128')

import osm2geojson
geojson = osm2geojson.xml2geojson(bbox.toXML())
```

My exception with osm2geojson is the following:

```
line 264, in multiline_realation_to_shape
    refs_index[member['ref']]['used'] = rel['id']
KeyError: 8835435
```

and with osmtogeojson the exception is:

```
line 21, in _preprocess
    for elem in j["elements"]:
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you print the type of bbox:

```
print(type(bbox))
<class 'OSMPythonTools.api.ApiResult'>
```

You can try it:

```
print(bbox.tags())
{'alt_name': 'London Cycle Network route 23',
 'colour': '#0198E1',
 'cycle_network': 'GB:London Cycle Network',
 'name': 'LCN 23',
 'network': 'lcn',
 'ref': '23',
 'ref:colour': '#0198E1',
 'ref:colour_bg': 'white',
 'ref:colour_tx': 'white',
 'route': 'bicycle',
 'type': 'route'}

print(type(bbox.tags()))
<class 'dict'>
```

https://github.com/mocnik-science/osm-python-tools/blob/master/docs/element.md

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this (although not through python) is to use the [ogr library](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html).
Download and install the library, then:

```
 ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" ".outputFile.geojson" "inputFile.osm" lines
```

Please note that due to the different way each format handles layers, you may have to change the last argument from lines to whichever layer you are interested in.

Also see [this link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/339075/convert-large-osm-files-to-geojson).